# How can I use Windows 10 unattended, without getting keylogged and sending everything to Microsoft?

Tags: windows-10-preview, unattended, keylogger

I would really like to test the technical preview of Windows 10.
I don't want to just install a few programs on it and see if they work, I also don't just want to quickly check out the new functionality.

I want to use it as my actual main system for a few weeks/months (and yes I know you're not supposed to do that) meaning that some sensitive data like source codes to some of my projects will be on that machine.
I don't want to help Microsoft to improve Windows, I just want to experience all the system changes and brace myself as a developer up for what might be coming soon.
But from what I heard, everything you do on the machine is being sent to Microsoft.
Since it is only a preview, I really don't want to rely on their encryption etc and I simply don't want my files being sent over the Internet to anyone and I also don't want my keystrokes and my whole usage patterns to be sent to anyone.

So my question is: How can I use Windows 10 unattended, without getting keylogged and sending everything to Microsoft?

What I did so far:
I did not use the Express settings during the installation. I selected customize.
And here are the settings that I used:

```
[Off] Automatically get device drivers, apps and info for new devices  
[Off] Automatically update my apps  
[Off] Use Smartscreen [...]  
[On]  Send a Do Not Track request [...] in IE  
[Off] Use compatibility lists for IE [...]  
[Off] Send some location based data to MS [...]  
[Off] Send MS info about how I use Help [...]  
[Off] Use Bing [...] let MS use my search history, location and some acc info [...]  
[Off] In IE, use page prediction [...]  
[Off] Let apps use my name and picture  
[Off] Let apps use my advertising ID [...]  
[Off] Let Windows and apps request my location [...]  
[Off] Get better protection from malware by sending info and files to MS [...]
```

I also did not create a Microsoft account or logged in into an existing one, I just skipped that stuff and went with a normal Windows account.
Then I installed Firefox, so I won't have to use IE.

What else will I have to do now?

Is there maybe a list of hosts/IPs that I could block using the hosts file?

Comment: Unplug the network cable, and don't join any wireless network?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling As I already said, I want to use it as my actual main system and I will obviously need to use the Internet on that.

Comment: Don't run beta test software if you don't want to participate in making it workable. Else figure out the mothership links and block them in your hosts file.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Beta software isn't meant to collect usage data, beta simply means it's not stable yet. I also want to help making Windows better, but this is not gonna happen by sending them all my personal information, passwords and private data. I'm also pretty sure that it's not illegal to modificate the system to not send this data to MS. Your second sentence doesn't help at all. If I knew how to do that I would obviously not be here.

Comment: Not necessarily. For example in Internet Explorer, if they want debug dumps back, they'll also want to know the website that caused the issue so they can tell for example if it's a javascript engine issue, a css render, etc. I've already been through this many beta tests ago with Internet Explorer. They're trying to find why it breaks, they need enough information to figure that out. They don't really care what you're viewing, but what breaks their browser is another issue altogether. And they're not interested in login credentials either.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why not use a firewall (either software or hardware) and block all system components from connecting to the Internet? Since you don't know what all the Microsoft addresses the system is using to phone home are, this is the best approach.

Comment: It doesn't even matter if they use my data, the problem is that my data might accidently be leaked, confiscated by the NSA or sent unencrypted over the Internet. Arakel, maybe you should read my question first. This is pretty much what I want to do, but I have no idea which addresses/IPs to block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an interesting [open source tool on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/3g7yph/opensource_app_to_disable_windows_10_tracking/) which seems to be able to disable all the tracking stuff:

http://blog.lifars.com/2015/08/05/app-to-disable-windows-10-tracking-features/
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Please don't take this the wrong way, but: stop using the product. That's really the only way you're going to prevent anything from being sent.

1. It's preview. It's not even beta. Besides this meaning things will break horribly, it means Microsoft released this so people can see whats coming down the pipe, and MORE IMPORTANTLY to get feedback on how things work.
2. It's part of the EULA. In return for you checking out their new version for free, they're *potentially* collecting information about your usage so they can <strike>do whatever they want with it</strike> make the product work better.
3. Microsoft makes it pretty clear: don't use this for real work. You've mentioned you know this, and want to do it anyway. This sorta makes you a bad person. :)
4. Usage information will (probably -- within like 99.73% confidence) not be sent once the product RTMs.

All of those things aside, consider Windows Update. Do you want it running? If so, checking in some of this information is part of the process. You can't have one without the other. Conversely, if you block all things *.microsoft.com then you don't get updates and things will continue to explode.

Comment: 1. Nothing broke so far, everything worked fine. 2. In Germany I definitely have the right to modify and disassemble any program I want as long as I'm not doing it commercially. 3. No, wtf, I disagree. 4. I doubt that... And If I should feel the need to get updates I could use third party software to download the updates from another computer.

Comment: Btw you can't even know that "the only way you're going to prevent anything from being sent" is not using the product. But you seem to be kind of person who tells people to cut their Internet lines instead of getting an AV anyway...

Comment: 1. Yay! But still... preview. Things break. 2. I'm not saying you HAVE to send them information in return for using the product. I'm saying that's *their* intention for letting you use the product. It's not a question of legality, but of the spirit of the agreement. 3. Ok. You're wanting to do what they explicitly said don't do, and further asking how to circumvent the mechanisms they put in place to make the product better. +1. Also, it was a joke. 4. Internet connected, updates off, and preview OS. Really?

Answer (score -1):

Not every keystroke is being sent to microsoft. Only things that you search using inbuilt search or IE/Edge. along with some usage details. i.e. what apps you use and for how long. You can disable these telemetry via third party tools easily.
IMO, this is what you get for using an free os from a for-massive-profit organisation. Windows 10 is a very good OS and microsoft have updated windows 7 and 8.1 to send the same data as well.

Solution, Use A different OS for private or sensitive task